# Slow queries for large tables using H2 database

Tags: sql, playframework, playframework-2.0, h2, ebean

I have a Play app (2.3.4 java) that uses Ebean and H2.

I have a large table (500000 rows) and when I ask this query, I get the results after about 20 seconds (decent laptop from 2014)

```
return new Finder<>(Long.class, Event.class).where()
            .where().eq("author.id", getId())
            .orderBy("id desc")
            .findPagingList(20)
            .setFetchAhead(false)
            .getPage(page);
```

It basically means that I want the last 20 rows of my table. How can I improve the performance?

Comment: Just shooting: if your model contains many relations it may waste time for fetching them, try to use `select("...")` and `fetch("...")` to limit fetched resources, also turn in statement loggin for Ebean to see what exactly it does during the querying DB

Comment: @biesior I tried select and fetch but It didn't helped. But only if I remove the line '.orderBy("id desc")' , every thing will be fast! even though '.orderBy("id asc")'  didn't change the performance, ... so How can get the latest X entries, with good performance? thanksss

Comment: @biesior these performances that I mention are in the debug mode (not production). do you think I will see a big improvement in production mode?

Comment: I don't think that dev environment slows down the queries such much... log via  H2 console into your database and try this query there, also check if field is indexed properly

Answer (score 1):

Firstly note that findPagingList() has been removed from Ebean's API as it was noted that people were using it incorrectly ... so you can only use findPagingList() on old Ebean versions.

Generally if you are going to return/iterate a lot of rows make sure you use findEach()/findEachWhile() ... and in old Ebean you'll see findIterate() which does basically the same thing.

If this query truely returns 20 rows in about 20 seconds then you should get the query explain plan and edit your question including the full SQL that is executed and the SQL explain plan.

If your query is returning many rows ... then it is reasonably likely that you should NOT be using findPagingList() and instead using findIterate() ... or better yet update to latest Ebean and use findEach() - especially if you are using Java 8.